# onClick method doesn't trigger when i click the Views

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
package com.example.sudoku;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        View continueButton=findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View newButton=findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
        View aboutButton=findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(Sudoku.this);
        View exitButton=findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(Sudoku.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i=new Intent(Sudoku.this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.exit_button:
            finish();
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

when i click views-buttons nothing happens 
i know that views-buttons are not connected with the on click method at all because when i define on click method into the x m l file it works fine,any help please i am new to android programming,thnx

Comment: did you enabled the actionListener for view while declaring it?

Comment: no i didn't,in x m l file you mean??

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define listener for other 2 buttons that is new & continue. Click on your exit button and see how it responds. Does it finish the application? If so you are on the right track.

Comment: i know about the other 2 buttons,this is not my problem...my problem is that about and exit views aren't responding

Comment: Could you post all the xmls and Activities.

Answer (score 1):

change onClick() method like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i=new Intent(Sudoku.this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.exit_button:
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.new_button:
        newButtonClicked(); // do your work here
        break;
    case R.id.continue_button:
        continueButtonClicked(); // do work
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write the cases for remaining buttons also,

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
      case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i=new Intent(Sudoku.this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
      case R.id.exit_button:
        finish();
        break;
      case R.id.continueButton:
       //your function
        break;
      case R.id.newButton:
       //your function
        break;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `View exitButton=findViewById(R.id.exit_button);` with
   `View exitButton=(View)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);`

Comment: i have try this already (this is a cast think) but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to pass add the onClick attribute to your xml. In the xml element you want to handle a click for, add this line:

```
android:onClick = "AddViewX"
```

Then, in your activity class you want to create a method like this:

```
public void AddViewX(View v){
    //Write Your Code Here
    Intent i=new Intent(this, NextClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This way you don't have to set up OnClickListeners, which can get very confusing, very fast.

Comment: yes i did it that way and it works but i want to know why this isn't working thank you anyway